# Linq - Expression.And to join N elements BinayExpression

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, linq-expressions

I have a list of BinaryExpression and I need to join the elements of this list in a single "object".

```
IList<BinaryExpression> lstBin = new List<BinaryExpression>();
```

Inside my List I have this:

```
{(item.Field1 = 1)} //First Element
{(item.Field2 = 99)} //Second Element
//So on..
```

I need something like this:

```
(item => item.Field1 == 1 && item.Field2 == 99 && item.Field3 == 45)
```

I know that Linq has Expression.And, and I need to make a logic to implement this, but I couldn't. I tried to make a loop inside my list but Expression.And needs two Expression, and inside my loop I have only one.
After this, I'll make a Expression.Lamba from this single "object", like this:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(singleExpression, parameter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want (with LINQ):

```
var singleExpression = lstBin.Aggregate(Expression.AndAlso);
```

If you prefer writing a loop:

```
var singleExpression = lstBin.First();

foreach (var expr in lstBin.Skip(1))
    singleExpression = Expression.AndAlso(singleExpression, expr);
```

Comment: Actually, you should rather use the Expression.AndAlso instead of the bitwise Expressopm.And as described here: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/idof/archive/2009/08/26/expressiontype-and-vs-expressiontype-andalso.aspx

Comment: @eluxen: Yes; you're right. Don't remember how that slipped by me.